# How to make input box as required field if checkbox is checked and not required if not checked for particular row in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table in which I have input box and checkbox in each row . 
If i checked the check box then input box must be as required or add required attribute to that row input box otherwise required property as false.
This case is for particular row as every row have their input box and checkbox.

```
<table>
 <tr>
<td>S.no.</td>
<td>Required Capacity</td>
<td>Action</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type ="text"  id = "src2"/></td>//make this as reqd. ifchecked
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="makerequired()"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input type ="text"  id = "src3"/></td> 
<td><input type = "checkbox" onclick="makerequired()"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td>3</td>
<td><input type ="text"  id = "src3"/></td> 
<td><input type = "checkbox" onclick="makerequired()"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>

<html>

 <script>
  function makerequired(){

 </script>
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Now I have added my code -> Please check it and suggest me answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the required attribute on the click event. On the change of the checkbox - go up the DOM tree to the parent tr and then down to get the text input and then set the attribute as per the checked state of the checkbox.

I have set one of the text inputs as required and a background of red to demonstrate the outcome. Note that you do not actually require jQuery for this - it could be done with straight javascript.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]');
  input.prop('required', checked)
})
```

```css
input:required {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S.no.</td>
    <td>Required Capacity</td>
    <td>Action</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type ="text"  id = "src2" required/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type ="text"  id = "src3"/></td> 
    <td><input type = "checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type ="text"  id = "src3"/></td> 
    <td><input type = "checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```